# Creating new UIView in UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` which I use to load a UIView (`TempView`) as a subview from.

```
tempView = TempView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))
tempView.tempLabelText = "YAY"
view.addSubview(tempView)
```

tempView has one variable and one `@IBOutlet`.

```
var tempLabelText : String?
@IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
```

I added a statement `print(tempLabelText)` inside `awakeFromNib()` of the `TempView` class and its prints `nil`

I want to be able to change the value to `tempLabelText` from `ViewController` so when I add the subview, The label is shown with what I declared. What am I missing?

Files in my project:

1.`ViewController` - Creates tempView : TempView!

2.`TempView.swift` - UIView class

3.`tempView.xib` - `.xib` with one label inside. Outlet of label connected to TempView.swift.

Comment: You've said that your `tempView` has one variable and one IBOutlet, but in code above you assign another variable - `tempLabelInt`. It's not an answer to your question, but please, clarify that.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it. I had that in my project just to see if both Strings and Int were behaving similarly. I have since removed that.

Comment: Oh my god, im losing my brain cells. Nice point out Rob, I fixed it. I meant the awakeFromNib() method. Here is a link for the project if you guys want to check it out since I am all over the place :(.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Z-8IMBX2LcVTQ0RkdVRUxUSDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can someone please help me get the string value "YAY" that I declared in ViewController and show it on the label on the subview?

Comment: Yes, wait a little bit, I send you link to modified code.

Comment: Thank you njuri. This is actually part of a bigger project that I am working on and I have been stressing about this for the past 2 hours.
Essentially what I want done is I have one UIView, everything is the same but the data is different. The data is in my ViewController. Instead of creating two UIViews that are exactly identicaly, I want to reuse one.

Comment: Here's link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=38212153299581260228

Take a look and ask if you have questions regarding my changes. Upvote is appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think of trying this. Thank you for your time to help me solve this issue @njuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awakeFromNib()` method is called when you initialize your view here:

```
tempView = TempView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))
```

At this moment variable `tempLabelText` isn't initialized yet. You assign value to this variable only on the next line.

Comment: Ohhh got it, so how would I go about passing the string "YAY" and showing it to the label as ultimately thats what I would like accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The awakeFromNib method gets called when you initialise the view. It gets called before you set it's property.